# boto3 not able to access given region name while taking region provided by AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition, aws-lambda-edge

I have boto client like this

```
client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name="us-east-1")
```

I am using this client to detect text from image and deployed code in AWS region where Rekognition api is not available but provided the region-name where it is available in client. On executing/Testing the lambda function, it is giving

```
errorMessage": "Could not connect to the endpoint URL: \"https://rekognition.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

Why it is picking ap-south-1 as i provided in client-"us-east-1"

client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name="us-east-1")

But when I run the code locally with region-name:- ap-south-1 and in client

```
client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name="us-east-1")
```

its running wonderfully

but not running on AWS lambda

While successfully running when both the regions are same(us-east-1)

So great if anyone can provide any suggestion, Required Help soon!!!!!!!

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Comment: Did you assign relevant application access roles to lambda?

Comment: @mootmoot yes i have assigned

Comment: Can you try `sess= boto3.session(region_name="us-east-1")` then only create the rekognition client `rekognition = sess.client('rekognition')`.  Sometime new boto3 service client doesn't pass the region_name along.

Answer (score 0):

As on March 15th 2018, AWS Rekogniton is not supported in `Mumbai` (**ap-south-1**)

See supported regions: [Amazon Rekognition - Available Regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#rekognition_region)

Comment: but i have provided us-east-1 in boto configuration client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name="us-east-1") good if you can help fast